# Azure DevOps YAML: Publish variables as artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I need some variables that are produced during the yaml build pipeline in a classic release pipeline, but publish artifacts expects files.

I know there are standard variables carried between build and release pipelines, but none of these matches my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you want to do this, but the obvious solution is to dump the variables into a file using an inline script, then publish the file as an artifact.

Comment: An example is the tag of the image(s) pushed into a container registry - if the release pipeline just uses :latest, then I can't flow the same image through the release pipeline stages. Can't change to multi-stage pipelines until they are more feature compatible with existing release pipelines.

Comment: Tag the container with the build ID.

Comment: Gets more complicated, the build Id value is not a valid docker image tag, I'll have a play with PowerShell ConvertFrom-Json and ConvertTo-Json

Comment: The build ID, not the build name. The build ID is an integer.